# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get the following code to compile and run in TypeScript.

I am not sure why `funcMap` is giving me problems. If I try this in pure JavaScript, I am told that `this.funcMap.k1` is not a function?

```
const obj = {

  foo: function () { console.log("foo") },
  bar: function () { console.log("bar") },

  funcMap: {
    k1: this.foo,
    k2: this.bar
  },

  dump: function () {
    this.funcMap.k1();    // --> foo
    this.funcMap["k2"](); // --> bar
  }

}

obj.dump();
```

The error message is:

```
main.ts:7:14 - error TS7017: Element implicitly an 'any' type 
because type 'typeof globalThis' no index signature.

7     k1: this.foo,
               ~~~

main.ts:8:14 - error TS7017: Element implicitly an 'any' type 
because type 'typeof globalThis' no index signature.

8     k2: this.bar
               ~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the following solution. It was to change funcMap into a function to return the mapping object.

"user2541867" also provided an answer, however it might be the case you cannot or do not want to move the function into the global space.

```
const obj = {

  foo: function () { console.log("foo") },
  bar: function () { console.log("bar") },

  funcMap: function () {
    return {
      k1: this.foo,
      k2: this.bar
    }
  },

  dump: function () {
    const mapped = this.funcMap();
    mapped.k1();    // --> foo
    mapped["k2"](); // --> bar
  }

}

obj.dump();
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because `this` keyword inside object is not this object itself, it is global context such as `window` in browsers or `global` in node.js.

`this` will point to object inside a function, but not as object property.

To fix your code I'd move those functions to separate constants:

```js
const foo = function () { console.log("foo") }
const bar = function () { console.log("bar") }

const obj = {
  foo, // shortcut for foo: foo
  bar,

  funcMap: {
    k1: foo,
    k2: bar
  },

  dump: function () {
    this.funcMap.k1();    // --> foo
    this.funcMap["k2"](); // --> bar
  }

}

obj.dump();
```

Comment: OK now it make sense, I had a hunch it was something to do with "this" but just couldn't figure out why on the object property. I did come up with an alternative solution, I ended up turning funcMap into a function to returned the mapped object.